# collapse text by 2 ID's in a row

Tags: r, function, aggregate

I have a question similar to this topic: "Collapse text by group in data frame [duplicate]"

```
group text
a a1
a a2
a a3
b b1
b b2
c c1
c c2
c c3
c c4
```

I would like to collapse by two sequential ID's (not the whole ID group)

```
group text
a a1a2
a a2a3
b b1b2
c c1c2
c c2c3
c c3c4
```

Comment: What do you want done if there is only 1 row in a group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternative `tidyverse` answer:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(text=paste0(lag(text),text)) %>% slice(-1)
```

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
dat[, paste0(shift(text,1), text)[-1], by=group]

#   group   V1
#1:     a a1a2
#2:     a a2a3
#3:     b b1b2
#4:     c c1c2
#5:     c c2c3
#6:     c c3c4
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(text = c(paste0(text[1:(n()-1)],text[2:n()]),NA)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(text))
```

or

```
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(text = list(paste0(text[1:(n()-1)],text[2:n()]))) %>% 
  unnest
```

> ```
>   group  text
> 1     a  a1a2
> 2     a  a2a3
> 3     b  b1b2
> 4     c  c1c2
> 5     c  c2c3
> 6     c  c3c4
> ```

The code above assumes the group length is always greater than one. If there are single-row groups, you'll need an `if` statement to treat them differently. For example, if we add a row with group="d" and text="d1" you could do this:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(text = if(n()==1) list(text) else list(paste0(text[1:(n()-1)],text[2:n()]))) %>% 
  unnest
```

> ```
>   group  text
>   <chr> <chr>
> 1     a  a1a2
> 2     a  a2a3
> 3     b  b1b2
> 4     c  c1c2
> 5     c  c2c3
> 6     c  c3c4
> 7     d    d1
> ```

Comment: Variation - `dat %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(text=paste0(lag(text),text)) %>% filter(row_number()!=1)`

Comment: I like it. More succinct. You should add it as an answer. Also, for the last line, you could do `slice(2:n())`.

Comment: Thanks. I get error messages with both. With the first one I get this: Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : Column `  ` Unreachable. With the second option I get: Error: unexpected '=' in:
"  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(text ="   I will try the variation by thelatemail

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you. I had a problem in the dataframe which I removed. I have got it to work using the variation by thelatemail.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
 unlist(by(df2$text,df2$group,function(x)paste0(head(x,-1),x[-1])))
    a1     a2      b     c1     c2     c3 
 "a1a2" "a2a3" "b1b2" "c1c2" "c2c3" "c3c4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `base R` option with `split` and `stack`

```
stack(lapply(split(df1$text, df1$group), function(x) paste0(x[-length(x)], x[-1])))[2:1]
```